# Change a Static Website to a Dynamic One

Tags: seo, web-development, static-content

What is the best way to change a static to a dynamic website? I know how to create the exact same page, but not with the same url. I don't want to lose any visitor of my current page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will depend on the server software, website framework, and type of hosting, which in turn should depend on the desired features of the website (i.e. the reason a dynamic site is desired). I recommend adding a lot more detail to pare this question down; the way it's currently written, I believe a decent answer would need to be book-length.

Comment: While I agree with @MaximillianLaumeister - and what I am suggesting is arguably not a best practice, a "low hanging fruit" way  of doing this would be to make your server recognise the pages as needing to be processed through PHP, and then add PHP to your code.   A better way might be to set up your page using your preferred framework, and then use redirects (either embedded in the framework or at the web server level) to redirect clients from the old to the new page with a 301 redirect.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide more information such as language/technology in use and sample before and after urls.